# MariaDb timediff function is calculating wrong numbers of hours

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Time difference between 8 pm to 6 am should be 10 hours but it is giving 14 hours

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TIME('2018-06-01 20:00:00'),TIME('2018-06-02 06:00:00'))) AS NoofHours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct data type:

```
SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2018-06-01 20:00:00'),
                     TIMESTAMP('2018-06-02 06:00:00'))) AS NoofHours
                     -- TIME != TIMESTAMP
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cb55a816aee5ba3d3d3cbd08c4763efd)**

`TIME` skips date part.

```
SELECT TIME('2018-06-01 20:00:00'), TIME ('2018-06-02 06:00:00')
-- 20:00:00                         06:00:00
```

---

Using `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,
                     TIMESTAMP('2018-06-01 20:00:00'),
                     TIMESTAMP('2018-06-02 06:00:00')) AS NoofHours
```

Answer (score 0):

As you con see if you select the parts separatly the TIME has no DATE part:

```
SELECT TIME('2018-06-01 06:00:00'), TIME('2018-06-02 20:00:00')
```

OUTPUT:

```
06:00:00 20:00:00
```

So 14 is correct

Here an example in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/41901)

Comment: i understand the problem i was using time function which is causing the issue